# How to deal with different version of Direct3D12 interfaces?

Tags: directx, windows, directx12, win32

Let's say I want to enable debug layers for a Direct3D 12 renderer, for which I need to create a `ID3D12Debug` object. Problem is, there are 6 different version of this: from `ID3D12Debug` and `ID3D12Debug2` all the way to `ID3D12Debug6`. Ideally, I want to enable as many debug facilities as I can.

So, what is the proper way to deal with this? Should I first create `ID3D12Debug`, enable its facilities, and then go down the line (calling each interface's newly added functions), or should I first try to create a `ID3D12Debug6` and call all possible functions on it, unless the creation fails in which case I try to do the same with `ID3D12Debug5`, and so on.

In other words, should I go bottom-up or top-down?

PS. Additionally, is there some resource which lists the minimum supported interface versions for each Windows version? Or should we always start from the very first interface ad climb up from there?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Direct3D, but those numbers like `ID3D12Debug5` are meant to describe `Direct3D 12.5`, `ID3D12Debug6` is meant to describe `Direct3D 12.6` and so on. Wouldn't you need to enable only the one that corresponds to the version you are building against? My understanding is that those are meant to "replace" each other, so having multiple interfaces for different versions at the same time feels wrong. I'm learning Direct3D myself so happy to be corrected if I'm wrong.

Comment: @TomTsagk While a bigger number corresponds to newer function, there is no correspondence between the interface suffix and D3D version. If we make a latest one supported on the machine, we will have to track which one was made and what is supported with that. If we make the oldest one, we will have to QueryInterface new ones any time we need new functionality. Both have pros and cons, hence the question.

Comment: You start from ID3D12Debug because it's the only one that can be created from scratch (from a function, ie: D3D12GetDebugInterface). Then QueryInterface from the one you need. Whether QI call succeeds depends on Windows version/upgrades/patches. That should be it, why would you need to "walk"? Just QI for you needs. And it's the same for all interfaces. As for documentation, it's not super for D3D12, used to be better for D3D11 where versions where documented

Comment: @SimonMourier The reason I needed to walk down the versions is that I might want to support as many debug functionalities as are available, in order to make debugging easy. The question then becomes: do I walk top-down or bottom-up?

Comment: If you want to support as many as available, you walk up, numbers are added with newer versions of runtime dlls (ie: Windows versions).

Answer (score 0):

The best option for broad support is to use the [DirectX Agility SDK](https://aka.ms/directx12agility) and just make your assumptions on the interfaces supported by the version you used since they ship with your application/game. You still need to handle cases where the functionality doesn't exist due to a lack of support in the current driver, but you can at least count on what interface versions are available.

That said, the specific reason for the interface versions is to support runtime flexibility. You should make your assumptions based on your minimum supported version of Windows 10 which at this point should be build 18362 or later. That's `ID3D12Device6` and later, `ID3D12Debug3` or later, etc. This is why all the DirectX 12 APIs take a IIID in their creation methods to make this easier to do.

Basically it comes down to which functionality you *require* and which functionality you want to *opt-in* if available but run without it otherwise. In particular, you can't count on *any* of the `ID3D12Debug*` interfaces working on a customer system as they only work when the *Graphics Tools* Windows optional feature is installed which is only a thing for developers.

So let's say you want to enable the `ID3D12Debug6` debug feature if it's supported, then you would write:

```
#include <d3d12.h>
#include <client/wrl.h>

using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;

...

#if defined(_DEBUG)
    ComPtr<ID3D12Debug> debugController;
    if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(debugController.GetAddressOf()))))
    {
        debugController->EnableDebugLayer();
    }
#endif

ComPtr<ID3D12Device6> device;
HRESULT hr = D3D12CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(device.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf())
        );
ThrowIfFailed(hr);

#ifndef NDEBUG
    // Configure debug device (if active).
    ComPtr<ID3D12InfoQueue> d3dInfoQueue;
    if (SUCCEEDED(device.As(&d3dInfoQueue)))
    {
    #ifdef _DEBUG
        d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D12_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_CORRUPTION, true);
        d3dInfoQueue->SetBreakOnSeverity(D3D12_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR, true);
    #endif
        D3D12_MESSAGE_ID hide[] =
        {
            D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_MAP_INVALID_NULLRANGE,
            D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_UNMAP_INVALID_NULLRANGE,
            // Workarounds for debug layer issues on hybrid-graphics systems
            D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_EXECUTECOMMANDLISTS_WRONGSWAPCHAINBUFFERREFERENCE,
            D3D12_MESSAGE_ID_RESOURCE_BARRIER_MISMATCHING_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE,
        };
        D3D12_INFO_QUEUE_FILTER filter = {};
        filter.DenyList.NumIDs = static_cast<UINT>(std::size(hide));
        filter.DenyList.pIDList = hide;
        d3dInfoQueue->AddStorageFilterEntries(&filter);
    }

    ComPtr<ID3D12Debug6> debug6;
    if (SUCCEEDED(device.As(&debug6)))
    {
        debug6->SetForceLegacyBarrierValidation(TRUE);
    }
#endif
```

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/)